# How to write query in SQL Server to select everything

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing java program and based on user input I have to perform operation.

If user gives me id (suppose id=3) then I have to execute

```
select emp_name 
from employee 
where empid = 3
```

else if user doesn't provide id then I have to show  everything from table (here is my question how to achieve this)

```
select emp_name 
from employee 
where empid = 'this should match everything'
```

I can't exclude where clause since I am using 'prepared statement' and just assigning values based on user input. id is of type 'number' I also want to know how to match it if id is of type 'varchar'

Comment: I don't see any Java code in your question.

Comment: where empid = empid should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use parameters, don't know Java to help with that part but you could provide NULL to the query as such.

```
select emp_name 
from employee 
where empid = (case when @parameter is null then empid else @parameter end)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers to your question. You can choose to implement what you feel more comfortable;

```
Method 1: Check the user input and construct 2 different queries: 
If the user enters "nothing" execute 
"select emp_name from employee", 
else execute "select emp_name from employee where empid=X", where X is the user input.

Method 2: Use only one query as follows i m wrtting a pseudocode):
if User.Input exists then X=User.Input else X="%"
then execute:
select emp_name from employee where empid like "X"
```

In any case, please don't forget to sanitize user input in order to avoid SQL injection attacks... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter is `NULL` when the `empid` is not supplied you can do the following:

```
SELECT emp_name 
FROM employee 
WHERE (empid = @parameter OR @parameter IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
Declare @empId int = 0;

select emp_name 
from employee 
where (empid = @empId OR @empId = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select emp_name 
from employee 
where empid = empid
```

This have worked for me I have checked for varchar